# Truth functions

Tags: logic

I know that a truth function is a function which assigns a truth value to $n$ propositional variables and then to an overall $T$ or $F$ value.

I have the following question:

How many truth functions $f$ of $n$ propositional variables with the property that $f(T,T,...,T)=T$?

I'm unsure of what this is asking me.

Answer (score 2):

There are $2^n$ rows in the truth-table for such an $f$, and since one row is fixed, all $2^n-1$ other rows can still be either T or F, i.e. still have $2$ options each. Hence, there are $2^{2^n-1}$ such truth-functions.

Comment: thanks for your response. why is one row fixed?

Comment: @juper It's the row where all variables are set to True ... we are told that for that one row, the $f$ should give a value of True

Comment: ah yes that makes a lot of sense. thank you very much!

Comment: @juper You're welcome! :)